# "Cannot open Vault" when accessing PasswordVault on a fresh machine via WinRM

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, credential-manager

When I connect via WinRM to a new windows machine, I cannot access the PasswordVault of the CredentialManager.

```
[Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] 
$vault = New-Object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault 
$vault.RetrieveAll()
```

and the error message is:

```
Exception calling "RetrieveAll" with "0" argument(s): "Access is denied.
Cannot open Vault"
```

When I logon to the machine with a Desktop or RDP the PasswordVault seems to be magically created and also the access via WinRM works.

Is there a solution to this? Maybe I can initialize the PasswordVault with a command?