# Access Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault over PS-Session on fresh Azure VM

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, powershell-remoting, credential-manager

This is essentially a re-post of this question: ["Cannot open Vault" when accessing PasswordVault on a fresh machine via WinRM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268627/cannot-open-vault-when-accessing-passwordvault-on-a-fresh-machine-via-winrm)

It is quite old, and we don't don't know how to "bump" it, so we are restating here...

After entering a PS-Session on a fresh Azure Windows machine, server 2012r2, like so:

```
$username = 'print-dev'
$uri = 'somevm.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com'
$port = '5986'
$remote_address = "https://" + $uri + ":" + $port
$password = 'somepassword'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $pass
Enter-PSSession -ConnectionUri  $remote_address -Credential $cred -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck)
```

... we run the following command and fail:

```
[somevm.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com]: PS C:\Users\print-dev\Documents> [Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault,Windows.Security.Credentials,ContentType=WindowsRuntime] 
$vault = New-Object Windows.Security.Credentials.PasswordVault 
$vault.RetrieveAll()
```

...with the following result:

```
Exception calling "RetrieveAll" with "0" argument(s): "Access is denied.
Cannot open Vault"
At line:1 char:1
+ $vault.RetrieveAll()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException

"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
```

If we RDP to the machine with the same user, print-dev, bring up a console and run the command that way, we succeed. Also subsequent calls over remote access will succeed after being run from RDP the first time.

How can we get around this access denied error?

What is the difference between a PowerShell command executed in an RDP session and powershell command executed in Remote PS-Session by the same user?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check the remote server's log to see if more details about the error are provided. Also, when running it via RDP with the same account, are you running cmd with elevated privileges?

Comment: @MichaelBurns where specifically should we be looking for logs? 
Also, we are not running commands over RDP with elevated permissions.

Comment: Windows Logs - there are different logs for security, rep, etc. You may need to do a bit of digging. https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/windows-logging-basics/